# How to change the fill of a SVG image with php?

Tags: php, xml, svg

I am currently trying to change the filling of any SVG you upload with php. Well, the upload is working, however I can't seem to find any solution on how to duplicate the SVG (I want the original SVG to stay the same) and to change the filling attribute with php. Has anyone some ideas which function I could use?

Here is my php code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p style="color:rgb(19, 107, 129);font-size:16px;margin:11px;">
        SVG-File to re-color:
    </p>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <p style="color:rgb(19, 107, 129);font-size:16px;margin:11px;">
        Hex color that it should be:
    </p>
    <input type="text" name="clr" />
    <input type="Submit" style="color:rgb(19, 107, 129);font-size:14px;" value="Send" />

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['file'])){
        $file = $_POST['file'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['clr'])) {
        $selected_color = $_POST['clr'];
    }

    $svgFile = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

    $myXMLData = $svgFile;
    $xml[] = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    echo print_r($xml);
?>
```

And here is my SVG code:

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" />
    <a>
        style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"
    </a>
</svg>
```

This is my first time working with xml and my second time working with php, any tips and changes which will make the code better are appreciated!

Edit: Here is the programm that I now have. It changes the fill attribute of a SVG and let's the user download it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<p style="color:rgb(19, 107, 129);font-size:16px;margin:11px;">
    SVG-File to re-color:
</p>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<p style="color:rgb(19, 107, 129);font-size:16px;margin:11px;">
    Hex color that it should be:
</p>
<input type="text" name="clr"/>
<input type="Submit"
       value="Send"/>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $file = $_POST['file'];
}

if (isset($_POST['clr'])) {
    $selectedClr = $_POST['clr'];
}

$svgFile = file_get_contents($file);


$myXMLData = $svgFile;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create 
object");
echo print_r($xml);

$FileContents = $svgFile;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($FileContents) or die('Failed to load SVG file ');

$rects = $doc->getElementsByTagName('rect');

foreach($rects as $rect) {
    $rect->setAttribute('style', 'fill: ' . $selectedClr);
}

$finished = fopen("finishedSVG.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open 
file!");

fwrite($finished, $doc->saveXML());
?>

<a href="http://127.0.0.1/Projekte/finishedSVG.xml" download>Download 
Now</a>
```

I also changed the SVG I was trying to edit, so don't be confused. Anyway, here also the code:

```
<svg width="400" height="110" >

    <rect
            width="300"
            height="100"
            style="fill:rgb(111,111,111)"
    />

</svg>
```

Comment: Welcome! You have a piece of code there, but I kinda miss what the problem is. Is `simplexml_load_string` not doing its job? What happens contra to what you expected? Or does it load correctly and do you not know how to proceed from here?

Comment: @GolezTrol Well, the `simplexml_load_string` does its job, it outputs the code of the SVG, but I can't seem to find a way to edit the string that it outputs/replace the filling. If you know how, feel free to share your knowledge. Thank you. :)

Comment: It looks like your SVG is invalid. `style=" ... "` should probably be an attribute of the `<a>` element. Now it is just content of that element. If it is an attribute, you can probably modify it easily using SimpleXML.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't understand what you mean with invalid. I thought `style = " . . . "`  does its job, it defines how to display the SVG. The output of the `symplexml_load_string` is : `Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [width] => 400 [height] => 110 ) [rect] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [width] => 300 [height] => 100 ) ) [a] => style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" ) )`. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, in that output you see it too. `width` and `height` are keys in the @attributes of the elements (svg and rect), but `style` is not an attribute. I think it should be, otherwise it's just text/content. So it should be `<a style="..."></a>` instead of `<a>style="..."</a>`.

Comment: @GolezTrol alright, thanks for your help, I'll change it and when I found out how to do it, I'll post the answer so that other users with the same problem can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have a better solution for this. Instead of making your own code I think this library can fulfil your needs. It's also gonna organise your code.

I just explain some code how to use

```
use SVG\SVG;  //import
use SVG\Nodes\Shapes\SVGRect; //import

$square = new SVGRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
$square->setStyle('fill', '#CCCCCC');

it's gonna fill this by grey colour

header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
echo $square; // it will echo your image
```

Also for more details visit [documentation](https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg). It's better to use this library. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your help. The problem is that it is for a school project I'm working on and my teacher told us not to use any libraries. I'll mark your answer as the most helpful for now and I'll try to find a solution for myself. Although I hope that your answer will help others, which try to do the same thing as me.

Comment: Cool. Well this is best performing library as I have seen for SVG PHP.